# Flood method-path finding in matrix maze, program won't go through small gaps

Tags: python, path-finding

I've made a program which tries to find a path through a maze by flood filling the maze with the numbers indicating their distance from the start point. When the finish point has been reached, the program returns the shortest path.

However, when the 'flood' reaches a small gap of 1 place in the matrix, the flood doesn't go through and I can't seem to understand why.

It produces scenes like this:

```
- - - - - - 
|4 3 2 3 4 5 |
|3 2 1 2 3 4 |
|2 1 S * * . |
|3 2 * F . . |
|4 3 * . . . |
|5 4 . . . . |
- - - - - - 
"with 'S' the start and 'F' the finish point and '*' used as walls."
```

At the two 4's on the bottom and right, the 'flood' should continue to the right and down, but it doesn't.

My code goes as follows:

```
def floodfill(maze,xs,ys,xf,yf):
distances=maze
distances[xs][ys]=0
n=1
while maze[xf][yf]=="." and n<25:
    for i in range(len(distances)-1):
        for j in range(len(distances[0])-1):
            if distances[i][j]==n-1:
                a=checkpos(distances,i,j)
                if "up" in a:
                    distances[i - 1][j] = n
                if "down" in a:
                    distances[i + 1][j] = n
                if "left" in a:
                    distances[i][j - 1] = n
                if "right" in a:
                    distances[i][j + 1] = n
    n=n+1
return distances
```

The program takes a maze (matrix) and returns a matrix with the distances.
The "checkpos" function checks in which directions the flooding can continue and returns a list containing ["up", "down", "left","right"] depending on which directions are available.

I don't understand why the algorithm refuses to go through the small gaps. Any ideas?

Comment: Your for loops don't check the right column or bottom row.

Comment: Oh,you're right, thanks! Quite weird I didn't see that...